# Undefined variable error in Gulp when adding to grey scale in Bootstrap 4 Beta

Tags: sass, gulp, bootstrap-4

I've started using Gulp for the first time today and I've been playing around changing some of the variables in the _variables.scss files to modify the theme. I added a grey to the grayscale in the colour system and when I came to compile this out to css with gulp I got an error:

> Error: node_modules\bootstrap\scss_variables.scss Error: Undefined
>   variable: "$grey-950".
>           on line 135 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss $body-bg:                   $grey-950 !default;
>   ----------------------------^

My understanding of the _variables.scss file and the greyscale was that I could just slip an extra one in provided I mapped it out like so:

```
// stylelint-disable
$white:    #fff !default;
$gray-100: #f8f9fa !default;
$gray-200: #e9ecef !default;
$gray-300: #dee2e6 !default;
$gray-400: #ced4da !default;
$gray-500: #adb5bd !default;
$gray-600: #868e96 !default;
$gray-700: #495057 !default;
$gray-800: #343a40 !default;
$gray-900: #212529 !default;
$gray-950: #222222 !default;
$black:    #000 !default;

$grays: () !default;
$grays: map-merge((
  "100": $gray-100,
  "200": $gray-200,
  "300": $gray-300,
  "400": $gray-400,
  "500": $gray-500,
  "600": $gray-600,
  "700": $gray-700,
  "800": $gray-800,
  "900": $gray-900,
  "950": $gray-950
), $grays);
```

Then I should be able to use it for the page background:

```
// Body
//
// Settings for the `<body>` element.

$body-bg:                   $grey-950 !default;
$body-color:                $gray-900 !default;
```

Is there a step I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `$body-bg` variable is `grey-950 !default`;

shouldn't it be `gray-950 !default`?

Comment: Totally didn't notice that! Thank you!!